# Weird javascript error with the .split() string method in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

So I'm trying to get some javascript code working that will filter a list of results by date on the page.

It works perfectly in FF on both Linux and Mac, Chrome works on mac, but I'm getting a very strange result on Chrome and Chromium on Linux (Ubuntu 10.10).  The following is the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
currentURL = window.location.pathname + "/order=vote/genres=/dates=";

$(".date").click(function() {
    var thisButton = $(this);
    if (thisButton.html() == 'Today') {
        var dateText = 'today';
    } else if (thisButton.html() == 'All') {
        var dateText = 'all';
    } else {
        var dateText = '';
    }

    console.log(currentURL);
    var splitURL = currentURL.split('dates=');
    var filterDateURL = splitURL[0] + 'dates=' + dateText;

    $.ajax({
        url: filterDateURL,
        success: function(response) {
            $("#show_container").html($("#show_container", response).html());
            $("#genre_filters").html($("#genre_filters", response).html());
            currentURL = filterDateURL;
            // add selected to this button, remove from other date filters
            thisButton
                .addClass('selected')
                .removeClass('unselected')
                .siblings("a")
                    .removeClass('selected')
                    .addClass('unselected');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

The split() on currentURL doesn't seem to be working in Chrome on Linux.

So if the url I'm building ought to be: '/order=vote/genres=/dates=today'

I'm actually getting perhaps: '/order=vote/genres=/dates=alldates=today'.

I have currentURL outside the function because other filters use the same variable.

So a user can filter by order, genres, and dates at once, and end up with a currentURL ending of '/order=distance/genres=GenreX/dates=today'.

The weirdest part is what happens due to the 'console.log(currentURL)' line before I use the split method. I put it in there to test what currentURL value it was using, and when I watch the console, this code works perfectly.

But if I close the console, it goes back to being broken!  So if I watch to make sure its not messing up, it doesn't, if I don't watch it, it misbehaves.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Where do you declare `currentURL`? Maybe it's overwritten?

Comment: It's declared right after (document).ready().

Comment: It's initialized there, but I don't see `var currentURL` anywhere. Not sure if that's intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your console.log() in a check like this:

```
if (console && console.log){
    console.log(currentURL);
}
```

This will make sure the code is not secretly breaking when you don't have your console open. What might be happening is when the console is open the console.log works because console is defined but when it is closed it might be trying to do a .log on undefined but you would never know because your console is not open. Awesome Catch22.

Comment: That will throw an undefined error if there is no console defined.  You need `if (window.console && console.log)`.

Comment: How would that throw an undefined error? you check console and then it will short circuit if it is undefined. If it is defined you then check for the console.log method